# R shiny, subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with simple Shiny app in R, but I face this error in the app:

> subscript out of bounds

The idea is to have a sidebar panel where you can choose vocal or consonant, and a barplot that visualize some letters with some numbers, clearly, choosing a vocal,vocals are with values, and so on with the consonant.

Here my code

First, I create the data:

```
x1<-c(1,2,6,3,8)
y1<-c('a','b','c','d','e')
z1<-c('V','C','C','C','V')
df<-data.frame(x1,y1,z1)

data.m <- melt(df, id=c(2:3), measure=c(1))
df2<-cast(data.m , z1 ~ y1)
df3<-as.matrix(df2)
```

Here the server code:

```
##server
function(input, output) {      

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({

    library(reshape)
    barplot(df3[,input$letters])

  })
}
```

and here the ui part

```
##ui


   fluidPage(    

  titlePanel("letters"),

  sidebarLayout(      
  sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("letters", "Letters", 
              choices=rownames(df3)),
   hr(),
  helpText("Types of letters")
),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput("Plot")  
    )   
  )
)
```

Well the error is the one in the title. Could you help me?
Furthermore, is there any way to put the data into the Shiny app to have them loaded when you start the app?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You are selecting columns in the df3 martrix that have names "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" with the select input that returns "C" or "V". You can put the data in global.R in the same directory with ui.R and server.R. Any variable created in global.R is available in ui.R and server.R

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the second point, if I am trying to use some data via odbc with an sql database, is the same?

Comment: Should be the same just put all the code that reads from the database in global.R and put the data in a varable(s) that you will use in ui.R and server.R